# Kill PID exceeding threshold

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write use a script as a workaround for a software bug for my org where the symptom is a specific PID will use endless threads.  I want the script to kill a single PID (PID since there will be more than one with the process name) if it is using more than X threads.  I'm testing with Chrome since it is easy to spawn multiple processes.  I've been able to piece together a script for listing processes and thread usage but not sure how to then pipe/feed that into stopping the process.  eg:

```
Get-Process -processname chrome |
Select-Object ID, @{Name='ThreadCount';Expression ={$_.Threads.Count}} | 
foreach 
if ($_.ThreadCount -gt 30) {stop-process -Force}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) to filter the processes of interest and pipe them to `Stop-Process`:

```sh
Get-Process chrome |
  Where-Object { $_.Threads.Count -ge 30 } |
    Stop-Process -Force
```